# Create directory and allow write access C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm creating a directory and subsequently writing to a file in that directory, but I get permission denied. It's within my user folder.

`Directory.CreateDirectory(filename);`

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(Path.Combine(filename, "t.pxp"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate)){...}
```

I've tried adding FileAccess.Write as a parameter to the File.Open but that's for the file itself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h4z99zb(v=vs.110).aspx
This is .NET Framework and doesn't work in .NET Core

How do I add ACL write access? I can write to files no problem, but I can't create a directory and then create a file in that directory.

Comment: I know about Directory.SetAccessControl, but it's not available in .NET Core

Comment: it is quite unusual that you should need to set that - does the new directory inherit a read-only ACL from its container(s)? are you on Windows?

Comment: @dlatikay I am on Windows. The way I understand it (I am a total beginner) is it should inherit it's ACL from the enclosing folder, but like I said, I can write to files, I just can't create a new directory and write in there. From the explorer GUI I can right click and add new text files easily.

Comment: [System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl (NuGet Package)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/).

Comment: It wasn't an issue with ACL at all. It was because I was trying to call the constructor on a directory :/

Answer (score 0):

its available in .NetCore

kindly go through this link.

**you can install NUGET in .NetCore**

**Install-Package System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl -Version 4.5.0**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_CreateDirectory_System_String_System_Security_AccessControl_DirectorySecurity_